# Youtube forward/rewind physical knob

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-bluetooth

I am looking for a way to map forwarding or rewinding a video on a physical knob, I looked on the YouTube API documentation but did not see anything. I know you can use the arrow keys on a keyboard, but can you do this with like a knob on to seek through a vid?

Looked on the YouTube API to see if there is a programmatic way to implement it, could not find it. Searched around a bit online, could not find anything.